# Xcode 9.2 - label values updated but is not shown in simulator

Tags: swift, label, delay, xcode9

I cannot make it working! Label's text is not updated in Simulator

Please might you advise how can I solve the issue.

P.S. After I click the button one more time the label's text is shown

```
@IBAction func doneButtonClicked(_sender : UIButton) {
    if textField.text == "" {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        textField.text = ""
        mainTaskLabel.text = ""
        iwillLabel.text = "I'VE DONE IT"
        todayLabel.text = "GREAT!"
        let delayInSeconds = 2.0 // 2 seconds 

        // do delay for 2 seconds. it change the value but not updating labels
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) {
            self.mainTaskLabel.text = "... DO NOTHING ..."
            self.iwillLabel.text = "I WILL"
            self.todayLabel.text = "TODAY"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what value of **textField.text** when you click the button

Comment: After i click the button for the first time the values are changed to "Do nothing", "I will" and "TOday" but these values are not shown. Only after i click the button again the labels texts are changed

Comment: the value of the textField.text is a "String" and the flow goes to else statement